# How to have the top Navigation Bar intact with RKSwipe or any Swipe view library for UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I want to have the functionality to swipe between multiple view controllers (kinda like Venmo, Twitter) in a UIPageViewController but many libraries like RKSwipe (https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers) seem to replace the default navigation bar with the view-controller navigation (like "First" and "Second").

I want that sort of navigation bar that lets you know which page you are on but plus the default ios navigation bar on top of that. How is that possible??

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @bodacious not exactly but refer here https://github.com/terrybu/CustomPageControlForPageViewController